# jQuery - Difference between a selected DOM element and a new element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm starting to use JavaScript and jQuery a bit more than just to do some shiny effects and I have a question about a fundamental thing in jQuery. I often have no idea what I'm *really* working with in jQuery.

For example, if a have the following markup:

```
<img class="image" src="picture.png" width="100" height="100" />
```

And in jQuery do

```
var img = $('.image');
```

`img` then is not the same as when I do

```
var img = $('<img class="image" src="picture.png" width="100" height="100" />');
```

But if I for example want to create a new image on image and run some jQuery functions on it, like `.css()`, I have to do:

```
var img = $('<img class="image" src="picture.png" width="100" height="100" />');
img.appendTo('.myElement');
$('.image').css("border","none");
```

Which is kind of a double step?

**My Question**: What are the different typs of things I'm handeling with here? What's the difference between the fist two examples? I want to understand what actually the elements are I'm daling with when working with jQuery/JavaScript.

**My Question [Update]:** I may have been a bit unclear, I don't want to know what the examples actually do, but what I select/create when I call these functions (a pointer to an DOM element, a string in JavaScript that represents HTML but still has to be added to the DOM to be displayed, etc.).

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you pass a **selector** (e.g. `$('.image')`) to the jQuery function, it does just that: **selects**. The jQuery object will contain all elements that are already present in the DOM that match that selector.

When you pass a HTML string to the jQuery function, it creates a jQuery object that contains the element(s) that the HTML represents. However, it doesn't automatically add them to the DOM, so you can't select them; you need to use one of the various methods to add them - `.append()`, `.appendTo()`, `.before()`, `.after()`, etc.

Your CSS manipulation example, however, is flawed, because you can chain jQuery functions together. You can combine that into a single line of code:

```
var img = $('<img class="image" src="picture.png" width="100" height="100" />')
          .css("border","none")
          .appendTo('.myElement');
```

If that's all you want to do with the element, then you don't even need to save it to a variable. If, however, you're going to want to use it again later, then it may be faster to do so; depends on exactly *what* you're going to be doing with it.

Comment: So it is possible to run jQuery functions like `.css()` on elements that are not yet added to the DOM like in your example? Is it correct to say that if I'm running functions like `.css()` on elements that haven't yet been added to the DOM, I'm just doing string manipulations?

Comment: Yes, because the `.css()` function is really just a shorthand way of setting the style attribute of the element.

Comment: @wowpatrick You can call *most* jQuery functions on elements that haven't been added to the DOM. Animations wouldn't work - or, at the least, wouldn't do anything - because there's nothing to visibly change.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between finding an element using a selector and creating an element using HTML code, is simply that one elements already exists in the page while the other is created and exists separate from the page.

You can do most things to a newly created object without first adding it to the page, for example setting a CSS style:

```
var img = $('<img class="image" src="picture.png" width="100" height="100" />').css("border","none");
img.appendTo('.myElement');
```

There are some things that you can't do to an element until you have added it to the page. Certain animations for example doesn't work unless the element exists in the page.

Comment: @jmoerdyk: Yes, you are right. I just copied the code from the question without looking for any faults in it.

Answer (score 0):

This selects all the divs that have `class="image"` in your page, and saves them in the img variable for future manipulation:

```
var img = $('.image');
```

so if you later do:

```
img.remove();
```

this code will remove all of the previously selected elements from the page.

although i am pretty sure you meant to select all the images on the page (not the divs):

```
var img = $('img');
```

---

whereas

```
var img = $('<img class="image" src="picture.png" width="100" height="100" />');
```

creates a new element which only exists in your img variable, and not in the webpage, until you decide to append it into the dom.

you can use the same manipulations on both element types, only difference is that the latter element is not yet shown in your webpage, it exists in the dom's limbo.

Comment: I'm sorry, i might be mistaken, Derek. Care to elaborate on which part i got wrong?

Comment: @Derek I'm confused. Your comment suggests you think saying it creates a new element is incorrect, then you post an answer saying the exact same thing.

Comment: @Derek, Firstly, I have edited those quotes in before you managed to reply. Second, your comment added absolutely no intelligence to this conversation. you should be ashamed for nitpicking instead of helping.

Comment: @Rodik - Calm down, I was just saying the quotes are missing there.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery function does far too many different tasks, IMO.

If you pass the jquery function `$()` some html, it will create a dom element wrapped in the jquery wrapper object for you.

If you pass it a selector, it will locate all the dom elements that match the selector and return them wrapper in the jquery wrapper.

In your example, if there is nothing else present in the document with `class="image"`, then your variable `img` is exactly identical to `$('.image')` (after you insert it into the document).  Accessing it as `$('.image')` is just a more roundabout way of getting back to your inserted element - you're basically searching the dom for the element you just inserted, rather than using the reference to it you already have in your code.

Answer (score 0):

To make things simple:

- `$("<img>")` - Create new element, which is the same as `document.createElement("img")`.
- `$(".img")` - Select an element in DOM.

Fun Facts:

- `$(function(){ /*blah.*/ })` - Run when DOM finished loading.
- [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) can actually do many stuffs!
- `$(".img", document.body)` - This is faster than `$(".img")` because it is scoped <sup><sub>(or whatever you call it)</sub></sup>.